# AngularJS: passing data through modular window

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show flash message when deleting record. I can not achieve notice to show up, although I get proper true response if I use console.log after getting response from server.

View:

```
<p ng-show="offerDeletedSuccess" class="someClass">
    Some notice
</p>
```

General controller:

```
$scope.offerDeletedSuccess = false;

$scope.open = function(offer) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        resolve: {
            offerDeletedSuccess: function() {
                return $scope.offerDeletedSuccess;
            }   
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    });
};
```

Modal Instance controller:

```
angular
    .module('someModule')
    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($http, $scope, $modalInstance, offerDeletedSuccess) {

    $scope.ok = function() {
        console.log(offerDeletedSuccess); // this returns false

        $http.post('/api/offers/delete/' + offer.id).
        success(function(data) {
            offerDeletedSuccess = true;
            console.log(offerDeletedSuccess); // this returns true, expression in html stays false
        }).
        error(function() {
            console.log('API error - config.')
        });

        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Comment: `Somehow this is not working`: how is it not working? What do you expect and what it actually behaves?

Comment: Notice does not show up.

Comment: Controller with modalInstance should be inside module controller

Comment: I have used console.log to review the issue, I have corrected above code. Somebody with an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution for this is using `$broadcast`. You have to inject `$rootScope` into `ModalInstanceCtrl`. When the data is ready, ModalInstanceCtrl will broadcast an event called `dataGet`:

```
controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($http, $scope, $modalInstance, $rootScope, offerDeletedSuccess) {
    $http.post('/api/offers/delete/' + offer.id).
    success(function(data) {
        offerDeletedSuccess = true;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('dataGet', offerDeletedSuccess);
    }).
}
```

We can handle that event in general controller:

```
$scope.$on('dataGet', function(value){
     //The value here is offerDeletedSuccess in ModalInstanceCtrl
      $scope.offerDeletedSuccess = value;
});
```

Comment: A broadcast is like some kind of a watcher? This is fully working, thank you.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. $on is a listener/watcher, $broadcast sends data.